# Zend Framework and REST API

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework

I'm learning how to write the REST API with Zend and now I'm at a stage to send the response to the client. Reading tutorials and the topic related articles I've seen many methods to do it like `setBody()`, `appendBody()` or just `echo` the data. My question is what is the difference between these three methods and when to use each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setBody()`. It's much easier to unit test your application's response if you can access the response body in a controlled way. If your controllers just echo data out this is much trickier.